# Can I disable the default sort for jquery $.post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a data structure that gets returned from the server via PHP which is sorted correctly based on timestamp.  When I view this data structure from the client it is sorted by the parent key.  Can I disable this default behavior or better yet how would I sort based on the timestamp via jquery on the client side?

Here is what the data structure looks like being returned from the server:

```
    [conversation] => Array
    (
        [7943] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1364062233
            )

        [9482] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1364125301
            )

        [9475] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1364128494
            )

    )
```

Here is what I see after it's returned to the client:

```
$.post("test_function.php", { function: 'test' }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

DATA:

```
conversation: Object
  7943: Object
    timestamp: 1364062233
  9475: Object
    timestamp: 1364128494
  9482: Object
    timestamp: 1364125301
```

Comment: Ordering of keys in an associative JavaScript array is not guaranteed and varies between browsers. You can extract the keys to a simple array, sort *that*, and iterate over the sorted keys to get the corresponding values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return an array of objects, not an object. Objects are unordered.